# Replace in array objects with same id using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I am new with loash and need help on this.

i have 2 objects:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "RHID": "2",
      "NOME": "Leonor",     
    },
    {
      "RHID": "3",
      "NOME": "José",     
    }
]
}
```

and

```
 {
      "data": [
        {
          "RHID": "2",
          "NOME": "Leonor maria",     
        },
        {
          "RHID": "3",
          "NOME": "José Leo",     
        }
    ]
    }
```

How can i replace inner objects with same RHID if they are diferent. Keep the second.
I remove duplicates with

```
Form.myData[Form.arrData] = _.map(
                                _.uniq(
                                    _.map(Form.myData[Form.arrData],        function (obj) {
                                        return JSON.stringify(obj);
                                    })
                                ), function (obj) {
                                    return JSON.parse(obj);
                                }
                            );
```

i want to replace if diferent.
Thanks a lot .

Comment: Can you re-phrase "How can i replace inner objects with same RHID if they are diferent. Keep the second." as it doesn't make sense ;)

Comment: sorry my english. Imagine i have this two array of objects . I want to replace the entries from first array that match the rhid of the second array of objects. Or replace if they are diferent as we can see they are. Kind of update operation and replace in collection when diferent.

Answer (score 1):

solved with merge the oposite way

```
$.merge( newData[Form.arrData],Form.myData[Form.arrData]);
```

instead of

```
                            $.merge( Form.myData[Form.arrData],newData[Form.arrData]);
```

and then

```
Form.myData[Form.arrData] = _.map(
                            _.uniq(
                                _.map( newData[Form.arrData], function (obj) {
                                    return JSON.stringify(obj);
                                })
                            ), function (obj) {
                                return JSON.parse(obj);
                            }
                        );
```

instead of

```
  Form.myData[Form.arrData] = _.map(
                            _.uniq(
                                _.map(Form.myData[Form.arrData],        function (obj) {
                                    return JSON.stringify(obj);
                                })
                            ), function (obj) {
                                return JSON.parse(obj);
                            }
                        );
```